# PHP - What exactly does ": bool" for example means after a PHP function?

Tags: php, function

On this site: http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-int.php

there's a function that checks if a value is an integer.

The function:

```
is_int ( mixed $var ) : bool
```

What does the ": bool" do exactly?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: @executable Not really helpful here.

Comment: [Return type declarations](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)

Comment: The return value of the function will be a boolean.

Comment: just means that the function will return a boolean value.

Comment: :bool there means the return type. That is how they are represented in the the documentation. `echo is_int (1)` will return true while `echo is_int (1.55) ` will return false or no value.

Comment: Note https://stackoverflow.com/q/24386569/476: the return type used to be on the left side of the signature; looks like they've switched it to correspond to the official type hinting syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a value of bool type.

Bool can be true or false.